# Which Message Service to use for unreliable network in Java

Tags: java, networking, jms, activemq-classic

I have a network of nodes. The nodes must be able to send messages to each other. Messages are only send from node to node (i.e. no broadcasts). The nodes know the address of the nodes they must send a message to. The nodes does not necessarily know who they will receive from. Some nodes (called main nodes) might receive messages from and send messages to a very high number of nodes (> 100k).

I want to be able to send persistent messages from one node to another. I want this to happen asynchronously even on an unreliable network. I.e. I want the message service to handle resends, acknowledgement etc. for me.

I have tried using ActiveMQ with a static network of brokers (only 2 nodes in my little setup) as explained in http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html. This works fine for my setup, but I expect that there will be around 100k nodes associated to one single node (called main), which would then have to have 100k brokers running to be able to forward the messages to all the associated nodes. All nodes may send sporadically and the main node might have to send to several (>10k) of the other nodes at times (note: No broadcasts, since they all receive different messages).

One setup I imagined using can be seen in this picture http://i154.photobucket.com/albums/s260/sheep_p/communication.png, where the cylinders denote queues. Here every node have an inbound and an outbound queue.

What technology can be used to achieve this and what kind of configuration of this technology is needed?

The technology must work with Java and have a free private or academic licence.

Comment: So you want to build reliable communication over unreliable network and with high scalability? Have you checked netty?

Comment: @nikolay-kuznetsov Thank for the comment I will definitely look at netty. To answer your question: No I have not considered it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never come across a out of the box technology that can do this.

One way to solve it could be to use the Queues (ActiveMQ), as in your illustration, internally and create an API using services such as Netty.io or Jersey (I have no experience with Netty, but have used Jersey for a similar application), externally. This requires though some bit of coding, but hey isn't that great? :)